# Using NodeJS with Express 3.x and Jade templates is it possible to just re-render one item for a previously rendered list?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I have been trying to find any post that can explain if it is possible to re-render one 'new' item (append) to a jade template list.

1. Say that we have a list of log-entries and upon first request we render a fetched list from a MongoDB collection 'logs', using res.render and Jades each functionality.
2. Since we like to retrieve updates from the database we also have a MongoWatch attached to that collection that listens for changes. Upon update can we execute some code that appends to that first list in the Jade-template?

   ```
   /* app.js */

   /*
       Display server log 
   */
   app.get ('/logs', function(req, res, next) {

     // Using Monk to retrieve data from mongo
     var collection = db.get('logs');

     collection.find({}, function(e,docs){

       // watch the collection
       watcher.watch('application.logs', function(event){
         // Code that update the logs list with the new single entry event.data?
       });

       // Request resources to render
       res.render('logs', { logs: docs } );    
     });

   });

   <!-- logs.jade -->
   extends layout

     block content

       div
         each log in logs
           div.entry
             p.url= log.url
   ```

Maybe i should use the template engine in another fashion, i am quite new to Express, Jade and really appreciate all you guys that spends your time answering problems like these..

// Regards

Comment: You'll have to look into [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets) or Ajax-based alternatives like [Long Polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling). [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) is a common Node.js framework for these scenarios. But, HTTP doesn't allow the server to push data to a client unless the client has an open request to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I was afraid of that being the case, wishful thinking on my part! Socket.IO has an npm module, i'll look into that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so i have looked up the suggestion from Jonathan Lenowski, thanks by the way!, and i came up with a solution to my problem. Thought i'd follow up and perhaps help someone else along the way..

Basically i am now using as suggested [socket.io](https://www.npmjs.org/package/socket.io)

1. So first install the socket.io npm module by adding it to package.json and run npm install, i used 'latest' as version.
   Next to use the 'socket.io.js' on the client-side you actually have to copy the file from the installed socket.io module to your javascript folder.

   ```
   Path (seen from project root is): 'node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/'
   ```
2. Setup DB, Watcher, Webserver, Socket and controller on server-side

   ```
   /* 
      SETUP DATABASE HANDLE
      in app.js
   */
   var mongo = require('mongodb');
   var monk = require('monk');
   var db = monk('localhost:'+app.get('port')+'/application');

   /* SETUP DATABASE UPDATE WATCH */
   var watcher = new MongoWatch({ format: 'pretty', host: 'localhost', port: app.get('port') });

   /* START WEBSERVER AND SETUP WEBSOCKET */
   var server = Https.createServer({key: certData.serviceKey, cert: certData.certificate}, app);
   var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
   server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
     console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
   });

   /*
       Display server log - controller
   */
   app.get ('/logs', function(req, res, next) {

     // Using Monk to retrieve data from mongo
     var collection = db.get('logs');
     collection.find({}, function(e,docs){

       // watch the collection logs in database application
       watcher.watch('application.logs', function(event){
             io.sockets.emit('logs', { log: event.data });
       });

       // Request resources to render
       res.render('logs', { logs: docs } );    
     });
   });
   ```
3. Include the socket.io javascript in layout

   ```
   /* 
      Add client side script
      in layout.jade 
   */ 
   script(type='text/javascript' src='/javascripts/socket.io.js')
   ```
4. Use the client

   ```
   /* 
      SETUP DATABASE HANDLE
      in logs.jade
   */
   extends layout

   block content

     script.
       var socket = io.connect('https://localhost:4431');
       socket.on('logs', function (data) {
         console.log(data.log);
         // Here we use javascript to add a .log-entry to the list
         // This minor detail i leave to the developers own choice of tools
       });

     div.row#logs
       div.col-sm-12
         div.header-log Some application
         div.logs-section
           each log in logs
             div.log-entry.col-sm-12(data-hook=log.status)
               p.method= log.method
               p.url= log.url
               p.status(style='color: #'+log.color+' !important')= log.status
               p.response-time= log.time
               p.content-length= log.length
               p.datetime= log.date
   ```
5. Use the functionality, remember that this flow is triggered by actually adding a row in the database 'application' and the collection 'logs'.

I use ssl thus with regular http we create a 'http' server instead and connect from the client with a standard address prefix of http://...

Also as an additional note, in order to use MongoWatch it is required of you to setup the MongoDB with replication set. Which is a mirror database that can be used as a fallback (dual purpose).

Cheers! And once again thanks to Jonathan!